# Memory modification when using strtol() and atoi() functions

Tags: c, atoi, strtol, memory-editing

I have the code (simplified a little for example)

```
char *op = CURRENT_PARSED_STRING.operand;
if(op){
    printf("%s\n", op);
    char q[] = "12h";
    int a = atoi(q);
    printf("%d %s\n", a, op);
}
```

CURRENT_PARSED_STRING is an instance of a structure that looks like this

```
typedef struct ASSEMBLY_LINE{
    char *marker;
    char *operator;
    char *operand;
    char *comment;
} ASSEMBLY_LINE;
```

when executing the line

```
int a = atoi(q);
```

CURRENT_PARSED_STRING.operand changes, and with it the op. In this case, the correct value is written in a.
Here is the result of the execution:

```
12h    //op content before
12 Q4R //correct value and garbage
```

Changing atoi() to strtol() does not work. This code is needed to illustrate the problem, in fact, I need to convert to a number exactly op.

Edit: yes, I made a mistake with the format specifier, but that was not the reason. I checked my program in the debugger, and it showed that CURRENT_PARSED_STRING is completely fine, right up to the line with atoi. I included all the flags when compiling, but that didn't work either. I don't really understand how to make the question cleaner because CURRENT_PARSED_STRING appears in different parts of the code and for full reproducibility I would have to attach almost all the code. But I see that the structure looks intact - the lines end with a null character, unused fields = NULL.

Comment: The question being asked here is unclear.

Comment: `atoi()` does not modify it's argument, and `strol()` modifies its 2nd argument.  Both returns a value and if you point that to a variable then it would modify memory.

Comment: Please revise question with a [mre].

Comment: Enable the compiler warnings, read the compiler warnings, fix the compiler warnings. If you use gcc or clang, compile with options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: You changed the format specifier in your question.  Do you still have an issue or did my answer resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely an incorrect format string.  The variable `a` is an `int` so you want to use the format `%d` (`%ld` is for `long`):

```
printf("%d %s\n", a, op);
```

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: OP changed format specifier in the question. You may want to change it back, since the change invalidates your answer.

Comment: @user3386109 I will just let your comment document it.